# How to write a Json decoder that converts from type ModelV1 to type ModelV2

Tags: json, decode, elm, decoder

I am finding it very hard to migrate old Model state to a new Model state.

Let's say initially our code had Model, and we persisted it to localstorage.

Now we want to add one additional field, "createdAt" to our Model, so I created a new type alias for the same.

```
import Json.Decode as D
import Html as H


type alias Todo = {id:Int, title: String}

jsonV1 = """

  {"id":1, "title":"Elm-Rocks"}

"""

jsonV2 = """

  {"id":1, "title":"Elm-Rocks", "createdAt":1479633701604}


"""


type alias TodoV2 = {id:Int, title: String, createdAt:Int}

decode = D.map2 Todo
  (D.field "id" D.int)
  (D.field "title" D.string)

decodeV2 = D.map3 TodoV2
  (D.field "id" D.int)
  (D.field "title" D.string)
  (D.field "createdAt" D.int)


result1 = D.decodeString decode jsonV1

result2 = D.decodeString decodeV2 jsonV2


type alias Model = {todos: List Todo}
type alias ModelV2 = {todos: List TodoV2}


main = H.div[] [ 
    H.div[][H.text (toString result1)]
  , H.div[][H.text (toString result2)]
  ]
```

How to write a decoder/function, that accepts any of v1/v2 format json string and give me a `ModelV2` record.

I am aware of [Decoder.andThen](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.0.0/Json-Decode#andThen) but I don't know how to write the implementation for `todoDecoderV1: ??? -> TodoV2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Json.Decode.oneOf` to try parsers and provide a default fallback by using `Json.Decode.succeed`. If you wanted to represent the absence of `createdAt` as a `0`, you could write your decoder like this:

```elm
decode = D.map3 TodoV2
  (D.field "id" D.int)
  (D.field "title" D.string)
  (D.oneOf [(D.field "createdAt" D.int), D.succeed 0])
```

However, to more accurately represent reality, I would recommend that your Model be changed so that `createdAt` is optional by changing its type to a `Maybe Int`. This is a great way to [make impossible states impossible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IcgmSRJHu_8).

```elm
type alias TodoV3 = {id:Int, title: String, createdAt:Maybe Int}

decodeV3 = D.map3 TodoV3
  (D.field "id" D.int)
  (D.field "title" D.string)
  (D.maybe (D.field "createdAt" D.int))
```

Comment: I was going through the "impossible state" talk, haven't finished it yet.
But createdAt is not an optional field, and I don't want to place maybe checks all over the code. Are you suggesting that every time schema changes, I use maybe? that would be a nighmare to dealwith. Since new code is guranteed to produce valid created at. This decoding is only done during schema migration.

Comment: That's understandable. You just need a sensible default if you choose to go that route. In my first `oneOf` example I used zero, but you can use whatever fits your business needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single model if you make the new field optional.

```
type alias Todo = {id:Int, title: String, createdAt: Maybe Int}

decode = D.map3 Todo
  (D.field "id" D.int)
  (D.field "title" D.string)
  D.maybe(D.field "createdAt" D.int)
```

Comment: thanks, but do check my response to using Maybe
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40702856/how-to-write-a-json-decoder-that-converts-from-type-modelv1-to-type-modelv2#comment68636044_40703098